Python Tkinter: Unable to make a calculator project
I am making a calculator project using Python Tkinter with an OOP concept, and I cannot figure out the problem with the function class. The function class is responsible for division, multiplication, etc. The window class is the canvas, and I have made two other class, for buttons and display. The function class is messy.
I think, it,s a conceptual problem in the code, but I really can't figure it out.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,size,title):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry(f"{size[0]}x{size[1]}")
        self.minsize(size[0],size[1])
        self.title(title)
        # self.attributes('-alpha',0.85)

        #placing button frame
        self.button_frame = Button_frame(self)
        self.display_frame = Display_frame(self)



#crating frame for the widgets
#animated slidebar
class Window_Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,start_pos,end_pos):
        super().__init__(master= parent)
        #general attributes
        self.start_pos= start_pos
        self.end_pos = end_pos
        self.width = abs(start_pos - end_pos)
        self.place(relx=self.start_pos,rely=0, relheight=1,relwidth=self.width)



#frame for the display
class Display_frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(master= parent)
        self.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both',side = 'top')

        self.text_input = StringVar()
        self.entry_fild = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.text_input)
        self.entry_fild.pack(expand=True, fill='both')


#frame for the button widget
class Button_frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(master= parent)
        self.pack(side='bottom',expand = True, fill = 'both')

        Frame_Buttons(self)

class Frame_Buttons(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(master=parent)
        self.pack(side='bottom',expand = True,fill = 'both',pady=5,padx = 5)
        self.buttons()

        self.funct = Function()
        self.delete = self.funct.delete
        self.clear = self.funct.clear
        self.eval = self.funct.eval
    def buttons(self):


        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="1",command=lambda:  self.funct.numb_press('1'))
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="2", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('2'))
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="3", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('3'))
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="4", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('4'))
        button5 = ttk.Button(self, text="5", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('5'))
        button6 = ttk.Button(self, text="6", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('6'))
        button7 = ttk.Button(self, text="7", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('7'))
        button8 = ttk.Button(self, text="8", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('8'))
        button9 = ttk.Button(self, text="9", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('9'))
        button0 = ttk.Button(self, text="0", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('0'))
        # opoaration button
        but_add = ttk.Button(self, text="+",command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('+'))
        but_sub = ttk.Button(self, text="-",command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('-'))
        but_mul = ttk.Button(self, text="*",command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('*'))
        but_div = ttk.Button(self, text="/",command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('/'))
        but_per = ttk.Button(self, text="%",command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('%'))
        but_bra = ttk.Button(self, text='(',command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('('))
        but_bra2 = ttk.Button(self, text=')',command=lambda:self.funct.numb_press(')'))
        but_eql = ttk.Button(self, text="=", command=self.eval)
        but_del = ttk.Button(self, text="DEL", command=self.delete)
        but_clr = ttk.Button(self, text="CLR", command=self.clear)

        button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        button3.grid(row=0, column=2)
        button4.grid(row=1, column=0)
        button5.grid(row=1, column=1)
        button6.grid(row=1, column=2)
        button7.grid(row=2, column=0)
        button8.grid(row=2, column=1)
        button9.grid(row=2, column=2)
        button0.grid(row=3, column=1)

        but_add.grid(column=3, row=0)
        but_sub.grid(column=3, row=1)
        but_mul.grid(column=3, row=2)
        but_div.grid(column=4, row=0)
        but_del.grid(column=4, row=1)
        but_clr.grid(column=4, row=2)
        but_per.grid(column=3, row=3)
        but_eql.grid(column=4, row=3)
        but_bra.grid(column=0, row=3)
        but_bra2.grid(column=2, row=3)


class Function():
    def __init__(self):
        # definingg variables for oparation functions
        self.Expression = ""

        # defining the functions

    def numb_press(self, numb):
        self.expression = numb
        self.display_frame
    def clear(self):
        self.expression = ""
        self.text_variable.set(self.expression)

    def delete(self):
        temp = self.text_variable.get()
        self.text_variable.set(str(temp[:-1]))

    def eval (self):
        temp = self.text_variable.get()
        self.text_variable.input(str(eval(temp)))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app =Window((500,450),'app')
    app.mainloop()


It is not clear what your issue is.  Give more information to clarify your issue and post error traceback if any.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File main.py", line 17, in init
self.button_frame = Frame_Buttons(self)
File "main.py", line 54, in init
self.buttons()
File "main.py", line 82, in buttons
but_eql = ttk.Button(self, text="=", command=self.funct.eval)
^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Frame_Buttons' object has no attribute 'funct'

Post the traceback in the question, not in comment.  You need to call self.buttons() at the end of __init__().

There are a couple errors here.

You're calling buttons before you bind the delete, clear, and eval attributes of Frame_Buttons. So when but_eql is instantiated it fails because there is no self.eval yet. If you move that call to the end you can get it running.
Your code is somewhat oddly/circuitously set up. Here's a version that has the logic fixed with minimal changes:

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,size,title):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry(f"{size[0]}x{size[1]}")
        self.minsize(size[0],size[1])
        self.title(title)
        # self.attributes('-alpha',0.85)

        #placing button frame
        self.display_frame = Display_frame(self)
        self.button_frame = Button_frame(self)


#creating frame for the widgets
#animated slidebar
class Window_Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,start_pos,end_pos):
        super().__init__(master= parent)
        #general attributes
        self.start_pos= start_pos
        self.end_pos = end_pos
        self.width = abs(start_pos - end_pos)
        self.place(relx=self.start_pos,rely=0, relheight=1,relwidth=self.width)



#frame for the display
class Display_frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(master= parent)
        self.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both',side = 'top')

        self.text_input = StringVar()
        self.entry_fild = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.text_input)
        self.entry_fild.pack(expand=True, fill='both')


#frame for the button widget
class Button_frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(master=parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(side='bottom',expand = True, fill = 'both')

        Frame_Buttons(self)

class Frame_Buttons(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(master=parent)
        self.pack(side='bottom',expand = True,fill = 'both',pady=5,padx = 5)

        self.funct = Function(parent.parent.display_frame.text_input)
        self.delete = self.funct.delete
        self.clear = self.funct.clear
        self.eval = self.funct.eval
        self.buttons()

        
    def buttons(self):


        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="1",command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('1'))
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="2", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('2'))
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="3", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('3'))
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="4", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('4'))
        button5 = ttk.Button(self, text="5", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('5'))
        button6 = ttk.Button(self, text="6", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('6'))
        button7 = ttk.Button(self, text="7", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('7'))
        button8 = ttk.Button(self, text="8", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('8'))
        button9 = ttk.Button(self, text="9", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('9'))
        button0 = ttk.Button(self, text="0", command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('0'))
        # opoaration button
        but_add = ttk.Button(self, text="+",command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('+'))
        but_sub = ttk.Button(self, text="-",command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('-'))
        but_mul = ttk.Button(self, text="*",command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('*'))
        but_div = ttk.Button(self, text="/",command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('/'))
        but_per = ttk.Button(self, text="%",command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('%'))
        but_bra = ttk.Button(self, text='(',command=lambda: self.funct.numb_press('('))
        but_bra2 = ttk.Button(self, text=')',command=lambda:self.funct.numb_press(')'))
        but_eql = ttk.Button(self, text="=", command=self.eval)
        but_del = ttk.Button(self, text="DEL", command=self.delete)
        but_clr = ttk.Button(self, text="CLR", command=self.clear)

        button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        button3.grid(row=0, column=2)
        button4.grid(row=1, column=0)
        button5.grid(row=1, column=1)
        button6.grid(row=1, column=2)
        button7.grid(row=2, column=0)
        button8.grid(row=2, column=1)
        button9.grid(row=2, column=2)
        button0.grid(row=3, column=1)

        but_add.grid(column=3, row=0)
        but_sub.grid(column=3, row=1)
        but_mul.grid(column=3, row=2)
        but_div.grid(column=4, row=0)
        but_del.grid(column=4, row=1)
        but_clr.grid(column=4, row=2)
        but_per.grid(column=3, row=3)
        but_eql.grid(column=4, row=3)
        but_bra.grid(column=0, row=3)
        but_bra2.grid(column=2, row=3)


class Function():
    def __init__(self, text_variable):
        # definingg variables for oparation functions
        self.text_variable = text_variable

        # defining the functions

    def numb_press(self, numb):
        self.text_variable.set(self.text_variable.get()+numb)
    
    def clear(self):
        self.text_variable.set("")

    def delete(self):
        temp = self.text_variable.get()
        self.text_variable.set(str(temp[:-1]))

    def eval (self):
        temp = self.text_variable.get()
        self.text_variable.set(str(eval(temp)))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Window((500,450),'app')
    app.mainloop()

Here's my version with a number of other issues fixed:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showwarning
from functools import partial
# Star imports are generally frowned upon

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, size, title):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry(f"{size[0]}x{size[1]}")
        self.minsize(size[0], size[1])
        self.title(title)

        # "Globally" shared variable
        self.text_var = tk.StringVar()
        # The frames we'll be using; note the captial casing (Python standard)
        self.display_frame = DisplayFrame(self, self.text_var)
        self.button_frame = ButtonFrame(self, self.text_var)


class DisplayFrame(ttk.Frame):
    """Displays the current input"""
    def __init__(self, parent, text_var):
        super().__init__(master=parent)
        self.pack(expand=True, fill='both', side='top')

        self.entry_field = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=text_var, state="readonly")     # state="readonly" prevents the user from typing in whatever they want
        self.entry_field.pack(expand=True, fill='both')


class ButtonFrame(ttk.Frame):
    """The input buttons"""
    def __init__(self, parent, text_var):
        super().__init__(master=parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.text_variable = text_var
        self.pack(side='bottom', expand=True, fill='both')

        # Add the buttons with a loop
        # Use `partial` due to how function binding works with a loop variable
        num_buttons = [ttk.Button(self, text=str(i), command=partial(self.num_press, str(i))) for i in range(1, 10)] + [ttk.Button(self, text="0", command=lambda: self.num_press("0"))]
        
        # Operation buttons
        but_add = ttk.Button(self, text="+",command=lambda: self.num_press('+'))
        but_sub = ttk.Button(self, text="-",command=lambda: self.num_press('-'))
        but_mul = ttk.Button(self, text="*",command=lambda: self.num_press('*'))
        but_div = ttk.Button(self, text="/",command=lambda: self.num_press('/'))
        but_per = ttk.Button(self, text="%",command=lambda: self.num_press('%'))
        but_bra = ttk.Button(self, text='(',command=lambda: self.num_press('('))
        but_bra2 = ttk.Button(self, text=')',command=lambda: self.num_press(')'))
        but_eql = ttk.Button(self, text="=", command=self.evaluate)
        but_del = ttk.Button(self, text="DEL", command=self.delete)
        but_clr = ttk.Button(self, text="CLR", command=self.clear)

        # Grid the number buttons
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                num_buttons[3*i + j].grid(row=i, column=j)
        num_buttons[-1].grid(row=3, column=1)

        but_add.grid(column=3, row=0)
        but_sub.grid(column=3, row=1)
        but_mul.grid(column=3, row=2)
        but_div.grid(column=4, row=0)
        but_del.grid(column=4, row=1)
        but_clr.grid(column=4, row=2)
        but_per.grid(column=3, row=3)
        but_eql.grid(column=4, row=3)
        but_bra.grid(column=0, row=3)
        but_bra2.grid(column=2, row=3)

    def num_press(self, val):
        """Appends `val` to the current text variable value"""
        self.text_variable.set(self.text_variable.get()+val)
    
    def clear(self):
        """Resets the text variable"""
        self.text_variable.set("")
    
    def delete(self):
        """Removes the last character from the text variable"""
        self.text_variable.set(self.text_variable.get()[:-1])
    
    def evaluate(self):
        """Attemps to evaluate the string that's been entered"""
        try:
            self.text_variable.set(str(eval(self.text_variable.get())))     # NOTE: `eval` and `exec` can be dangerous - they run whatever code is given them!
        except SyntaxError:
            showwarning(title="Invalid command", message="The entered command is invalid")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Window((500, 450), 'app')
    app.mainloop()


When answering questions, it's best to write about the changes you made to the code so that OP is more likely to understand the answer.
